# Finding the total number (state space) of non-equivalent matrices

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science

Given a general matrix of dimensions $(x, y)$, in which every element can have an $N$ number of discrete values, I need to find the number of all the non-equivalent matrices. Equivalent matrices are defined as ones that can be achieved from the same matrix through interchanging rows and/or columns.

The context for this is a Computer Science course - so I'm expected to iterate, and probably sum over different parts (for instance, iterating over $N$ - because it also includes the possibility for only $[1, N-1]$ unique elements). Iterating over the matrices directly cannot be done, due to a significantly large $(x, y)$ and $N$

The part I'm struggling with is how to describe the amount of equivalent matrices - because I know that the possible amount of unique matrices is $N^{(x \cdot y)}$, and just subtracting it from there would get me the answer I'm looking for - but I don't actually know how to describe that dependence mathematically. Alternatively, I was trying to get the amount of non-equivalent matrices directly, but without success. The most I could make of it is:

$$\Omega={N \choose x \cdot y }\sum_{i=1}^N({{x \cdot y \choose i} / \prod_{j=1}^i{j!})}$$

Where $N \choose x \cdot y$ are duplications of the same arrangement with different values (for instance substituting (0, 1) with (1, 2), ${x \cdot y \choose i}$ is the amount of possibilities to populate the matrix, and $\prod_{j=1}^i{j!}$ is the overcounting correction factor.

I couldn't reduce the problem to 1 dimension, as there is some correlation between certain arrangement of lines and rows. I have tried simplifying the problem by generating a list of occurrences per value, given the amount of unique values - and plugging those values into the inner sum - but that doesn't seem to work either.

Any help in improving the formula, defining the constraints on the matrix space, or how should I approach this problem in general would be much appreciated.

Comment: It’s possible that this sort of thing has been worked out by representation theorists into something very compact, but the standard framework for counting unique things up to symmetries is given by Burnside’s Lemma or its close cousin Pólya enumeration.  The symmetry group here is rather large, being $x!y!$, so a naive application is still impractical for large $x,y& (but large $N$ is no problem), but it does provide a way to formally describe the dependencies you seek.